# Tried to install React-native-maps and I got this error what does this mean?

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-native-maps

***Terminal***

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: instalawnrn@0.0.1 npm ERR!
> Found: react@17.0.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!
> react@"17.0.1" from the root project npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16.0 ||
> < 17.0" from react-native-maps@0.28.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/react-native-maps npm ERR!     react-native-maps@"*" from
> the root project npm ERR!   2 more (react-native, react-native-web)
> npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
> react@"17.0.2" from react-dom@17.0.2 npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
> npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">=16.5.1" from react-native-web@0.11.7 npm
> ERR!   node_modules/react-native-web npm ERR!     peer
> react-native-web@"^0.11" from react-native-maps@0.28.0 npm ERR!
>
> node_modules/react-native-maps npm ERR!       react-native-maps@"*"
> from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency
> conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or
> --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See
> C:\Users\kcopu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full
> report.

Comment: Please format console output as code, not a quote, to preserve linebreaks. It means what it says--that version isn't currently built for React 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package manager can determine whether or not react-native-maps will be installed. NPM does not work but you can install the package with yarn for example 'yarn add react-native-maps' will work instead of npm Install.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

> npm i --legacy-peer-deps

Node packages after this command will be installed perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

I am the same issue.
If I install with this command

```
npm install react-native-maps --save-exact
```

not work... but with this command

```
expo install react-native-maps
```

works!!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Did you use react native CLI?

Comment: @PapaKodi no he didn't. Instead, he used expo CLI